# Mysql - How to select record from table which has no relation

Tags: mysql, sql, join, non-relational-database

Is it possible to get record from non-relation table?
In this case, I have two records on table rating.
I want to get data from `idBengkel` on table rating then add them into column `idBengkel_2` on table bengkel_similarity.

> Note : Column `idUser` resulting how many records. So, number of record must match on all table. And idUser is not same with idBengkel_1.

---

Here is my tables :
bengkel_similarity

```
SELECT idBengkel_1, idBengkel_2, nilaiSimilarity
FROM bengkel_similarity
WHERE idBengkel_1 = 1 AND idBengkel_2 = 7
OR idBengkel_1 = 1 AND idBengkel_2 = 10
```

rating

```
SELECT idUser, idBengkel, nilai
FROM rating
WHERE idUser = 1
```

---

Here the result from all table :
Result of bengkel_similarity

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| idBengkel_1 | idBengkel_2 | nilaiSimilarity |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|           1 |           7 | -0.1692         |
|           1 |          10 | 0               |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Result of rating

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| idUser | idBengkel | nilai |
+--------+-----------+-------+
|      1 |         7 |     4 |
|      1 |        10 |     5 |
+--------+-----------+-------+
```

---

This is what I want :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+
| idUser | idBengkel_1 | idBengkel_2 | nilai | nilaiSimilarity |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+
|      1 |           1 |            7|      4|         -0.1692 |
|      1 |           1 |           10|      5|               0 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: But they don't relate. That the issue. You would have to have the same amount of rows and in the correct positions, or you can't. If they do have tho same amount of rows and the results line up exactly then you can do two queries then join the result arrays based on two separate fetches, but you would have to use your Server Language, like PHP.

Comment: I am using codeigniter 4 for server-side. But I think it need more times to solve the problem. I'll try if there is no solution.

Comment: FKs & other constraints are not involved in querying. They prevent invalid updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would qualify this as "non-relational". From your data and desired results, I think you just want a `join`:

```
SELECT 
    bs.idBengkel_1, 
    bs.idBengkel_2, 
    r.nilai
    bs.nilaiSimilarity,
FROM bengkel_similarity bs
INNER JOIN rating r 
    ON  r.idUser    = bs.idBengkel_1
    AND r.idBengkel = bs.idBengkel_2
WHERE bs.idBengkel_1 = 1 AND bs.idBengkel_2 IN (7, 10)
```

Comment: Maybe he refers the relation is not physically declared with foreign keys. But as you said it doesn't mean the data is not related...

Comment: Yes you're right @JaimeDrq because the tables has no foreign keys at all

Comment: The ``idUser`` has many datas. It is not only 1-10 as the ``idBengkel``. So, it could not be same with idBengkel_1 and I will get idBengkel_1 from input on server-side.

Comment: Please check the note. How if idUser has 4 records? Then column idBengkel_2 also must has 4 records.

Comment: I edited your query  ``ON  r.idUser  = 1`` because I will get the data from input. The problem is what if  ``ON  r.idUser  = 2`` etc? How can I change ``IN (7, 10)`` so that corresponding with the r.idUser's datas including the amount of it?

Comment: I've done with this answer! I made change ``ON  r.idUser = 1`` and then ``IN (SELECT idBengkel FROM bengkel WHERE idUser = 1)``. Awesome It's solved the problem by subquery. Please edit your answer! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

When I understand you correct:

```
select * from bengkel_similarity , rating where idBengkel = idBengkel_2
```

Comment: idUser is not same with idBengkel_1